# mod_rewrite rules for all web documents

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am in need of the rewrite rules and conditions to evoke a central PHP script for every and any web document requested on my server. Just to add, I do not want the PHP script to be evoked when requests are made for CSS, JS, PNG, GIF, JPG, and other media etc. I only want the script to be called for HTM, HTML and PHP documents in the root and in any directory or subdirectory.

The main stumbling point I am having is I cannot get the script to be evoked for any of the assumed directory indexes. Here is what I am getting:

- http://sampleDomain.com/test/index.html (follows the RewriteRule and evokes myScript.php)
- sampleDomain.com/test/test.html (follows the RewriteRule and evokes myScript.php)
- sampleDomain.com/test/ (does not follow the RewriteRule - it displays a directory listing)
- sampleDomain.com/test (does not follow the RewriteRule - it displays a directory listing)

Here are my directives:

- RewriteEngine On
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC,OR]
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
- RewriteRule . /phpDir/myScript.php [L]

What does the RewriteRule and RewriteCond look like to get every/any web document to evoke myScript.php?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
DirectoryIndex /phpDir/myScript.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !phpDir/myScript.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(php|html|htm)$ /phpDir/myScript.php [L]
```

#### Breaking it down

```
DirectoryIndex /phpDir/myScript.php
```

Sets the default directory file to be that of your script. So if you enter a folder that doesn't have index file, use `/phpDir/myScript.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !phpDir/myScript.php [NC]
```

Checks to make sure you're not requesting your central PHP script. Otherwise you could find yourself in a never-ending loop.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Check that the file you're requesting isn't already an existing file. In case you want to have other files instead of pushing everything onto your central script.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(php|html|htm)$ /phpDir/myScript.php [L]
```

This last rule checks to see if the requested file is of one of the file extensions (in this case `.php`, `.htm` or `.html`) and if it is, pass it to the central PHP script. This will leave alone other files, such as graphics, CSS and other media.

Comment: Thanks "Crisis of Indentity".

I tried it in a .htaccess file in one directory on my server and it worked. I need to do some server-wide cleanup before I can place this into my httpd.conf file and try on the entire server, but tanks for the solution and your step-by-step explanations -- it really helps.

FYI...I did get a warning message however:
[Tue Nov 24 07:50:10 2009] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.

So I am removing the [NC] option from the RewriteCond line being referenced.

Comment: Thanks, totally missed the warning about the NC sitting right there in the error log. Edited to clear up/out.

Answer (score 0):

Found it through persistent searching and testing:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /phpDir/myScript.php [L]